# sftp and chroot on debian

Tags: debian, sftp, chroot

I am experimenting with a server running Debian. It should replace my aging Apple server (and since the new Apple server is not a server anymore that is no longer an option).

So far everything goes fine, but I have a problem placing a user in chroot jail for sftp access. I am following this [guide](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/).

This goes well, but when I connect with a ftp client (cyberduck in this case) I arrive in the folder `/sftp/guestuser/`. I am not able to do anything in this folder, therefore (still following the guide) there is a folder 'incoming' inside the `/sftp/guestuser` directory where I can put/get files etc. But I know this will be confusing to my clients.

They just want to log in to a given sftp address and put/get the files they want. I have played around a bit with permissions and ownerships but I cannot find a way to get directly to the directory where I can actually do something.

After following the guide the guestuser directory that I go to after sftp-ing to the server has `root:root` ownership, the 'incoming' directory is `guestuser:sftpusers`, where sftpusers is the chrooted group for sftp in sshd_config. The guide is from 2012, but I guess the principles are still the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check first if the guestuser's home directory is set to `/incoming`.
The output of 

`grep guestuser /etc/passwd`

Should be like:
`guestuser:x:1002:1000::/incoming:/sbin/nologin`

If the home directory is not `/incoming` then

`usermod guestuser -d /incoming`

changes it to `/incoming`.

A client conntection to the sftp-server as guestuser should now end up in `/incoming`

Comment: Thank you @CaldeiraG for editing my question. I'm new to superuser.

Comment: @conditoHumana: The home dir for guestuser is `/sftp/guestuser`. If I change that to `/sftp/guestuser/incoming` I can not log in anymore. I think this is because of the ownership of `incoming` is not `root:root`. But as you can tell, this is all pretty new to me.